# how to play MP3 files at fast speed

Tags: mp3, vlc-media-player, media-player

I have MP3 file and the contents are continuous and slow. Is there any tool, which converts them to fast speed.

I am aware of the fact that with VLC, i can play fast. But, the problem is every time i have to fix the speed of the player.

The Question is, i dont want to manipulate/tweak every time i play the file. I wish to have permanent solution to play the slow playing MP3 files to play fast (some thing like saving the file with fast speed etc).

Comment: check [Increase Speed of MP3 With Command-Line Tool](http://superuser.com/q/90347/263)

Answer (score 5):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to change the timing settings so you can play it at its correct speed. It's free and an excellent audio editing tool.

Answer (score 2):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)'s `speed` predicate will allow you to adjust the speed of the audio file. `tempo` might also be useful.